# Fazer um If em c++ limitando as respostas

Tags: c++, if

O usuário digita o ano, mês, dia e temperatura, mas preciso limitar as respostas.

- `ano` não pode ser menor que `1850` e maior que `2021`
- `mes` não pode ser menor que `1` e maior que `12`, `dia` não pode ser menor que `1` e não pode ser maior que `31`
- `temperatura` não pode ser menor que `-50` e maior que `65`.

Tentei essa verificação mas não vai ...

```
cout<<"\nPor favor digite o dia: "; 
cin>>dia[i];
cout<<"\nPor favor digite o mês: ";
cin>>mes[i];
cout<<"\nPor favor digite o ano: ";
cin>>ano[i];
cout<<"\nPor favor digite a temperatura: ";
cin>>temperatura[i]; 
cout<<"\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n"; 
if ((dia[i] > 30) || (mes[i] > 12) || (ano[i] < 1850 > 2021)) { 
    cout<<"\nAlgo esta inválido"; 
}
```

O programa imprime uma mensagem dizendo que algo está inválido.

Comment: Você poderia colocar o restante do código para conseguirmos ter uma visão geral do problema?

Comment: Além de você não estar validando algumas coisas, isso é inválido: `ano[i] < 1850 > 2021`. Precisa verificar uma parte de cada vez: `ano[i] < 1850 || ano[i] > 2021`.

Comment: boa tarde, então não coloquei inteiro porque é um switch e esta incompleto, eu peço essas informações para o usuario e diante disso ele escolhe uma opção que vai usar essas informações por exemplo média das temperaturas...

Comment: legal talvez isso que fiz errado mesmo de não verificar uma coisa de cada vez... obrigada

Answer (score -1):

Bom, como você deixou apenas uma parte do código, tive que assumir algumas coisas para poder trabalhar em uma solução para você, como você deixou os dados como um array, e construí a solução com base nisso, usando um array `int` de apenas 2 elementos para facilitar a visualização, e a utilização de um `bool` para a construção de um loop para continuar pedindo dados até tudo estar correto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    
    int dia[2], mes[2], ano[2], temperatura[2];
    bool errado;
    //Vai pedir dados para os dois arrays, facilmente modificavel de usar uma variavel ou define no lugar do 2
    for(int i=0; i<2 ;i++){
        do{
            cout<<"Set de dados " << i+1 << "\n";
            
            cout<<"\nPor favor digite o dia: ";
            cin>>dia[i];
            cout<<"\nPor favor digite o mês: ";
            cin>>mes[i];
            cout<<"\nPor favor digite o ano: ";
            cin>>ano[i];
            cout<<"\nPor favor digite a temperatura: ";
            cin>>temperatura[i]; 
            cout<<"\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n"; 
    
            if ( (dia[i] > 30 || dia[i] < 1) || (mes[i] > 12 || mes[i] < 1) || (ano[i] < 1850 || ano[i] > 2021) || (temperatura[i] < -50 || temperatura[i] > 65)  ) { 
                cout<<"\nAlgo esta inválido! Digite novamente!\n";
                errado = true;
                i--;
            }else errado = false;
        }while(errado);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Porém como o Rafael Tavares mencionou, você não pode comparar mais de 2 coisas ao mesmo tempo no C, tem que fazer uma por uma, assim como exemplifiquei